# Extend a ViewController inside a container view in a scroll view

Tags: objective-c, nsobject

Essentially what I have is a view controller full of auto-resizing `UILabels` and what I am wanting to do is to have it resize the view so it will allow me to scroll through all of the text labels without cutting them off. It shows the first three fine but the last one always gets cut off.

I am using Storyboards with `AutoLayout` and have not modified anything in code besides the `UILabels`. I have already tried using a `TableView`, but did not like the feel of that and had trouble storing my custom objects in arrays.

Comment: Do you know how many UILabels you have to show at compile time (is it always four?) or is it some amount based on data you load at runtime?

Comment: Yes it is always the same number of UILables, however four out of the 12 can resize based on amount of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I did,

I got rid of the UIScrollView and replaced it with a UITableView with three NSMutableArrays. To get the UITableView to work I first had to load three NSMutableArrays with dummy data and then I had to call my object and print out an NSLog statement or else the app would crash. Finally I reallocated the array and put in the correct data. After all of this it worked.